# Get child of child using fork()

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, system-calls

I'm having some trouble on my Operating Systems class. I need to write a function in C where each child generates another child, and every parent can only have one child. I also have to print their pid's.

This is what I have so far:

```
#define MAX_COUNT 10

pid_t ex5_1 (pid_t pid) {
    pid = fork();
    if (!pid) {
        printf("ID %d Parent %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
        _exit(1);   
    }
    return pid;
}
void ex5 () {
     pid_t  pid;
     int    i;
     pid = fork();
     for (i = 1; i <= MAX_COUNT; i++) {
          pid = ex5_1(pid);
          int status;
          wait(&status);
     } 
}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Idk how to generate a specific number of child of child

Comment: Buy "specific number" you mean one?

Comment: Imagine X has a child Y and this Y has a child Z and on and on until a certain number

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think he wants a chain of processes `MAX_COUNT` deep.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons that’s it! Thx

Comment: Um.. increment a counter after a fork?

Comment: Or count down to zero.

Comment: You should take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Homework assignments are small, there's no reason you can't easily provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the man says about fork :

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So you just have to check the return of fork like this :

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    // error handling here
else if (pid == 0)
    // here you are in the child
else
    // here you are in the parent
```

At the end, to create a child in a child, you can do something like this :

```
void child(int i)
{
    int pid;

    printf("Child number %d, ID %d Parent %d \n", i,  getpid(), getppid());
    if (i == MAX)
        return;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        // error handling here
    else if (pid == 0)
        child(++i);
    else
        waitpid(pid, null, 0);
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;  
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        // error handling here
    else if (pid == 0)
        child(++i);
    else
        waitpid(pid, null, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `int main(void) { child(0); }`?

Comment: Also `fork()` returns `pid_t` not `int`.

Comment: @alk just for the printf thing, he want to print only in child, not in main process. And i think he understand better when it's decomposed like this.

Comment: @alk _The pid_t data type is a signed integer type which is capable of representing a process ID. In the GNU C Library, this is an int._

Comment: @MickaelB. Thank you very much! Now i understand the method! :-)